# Google authentication apache cordova

Tags: android, cordova, oauth, asp.net-core, google-authentication

I have recently created a simple mvc website in asp.net core. I added google authentication and it is working fine.
Now i decided to create an apache cordova hosted app for my application. All the app does is basically display the website.

Unfortunately, the google authentication doesn't seem to be working on android, because [google blocked oauth in webviews](https://developers.googleblog.com/2016/08/modernizing-oauth-interactions-in-native-apps.html). It does work on UWP though (not sure if it will still work after 20 april when google will start blocking even more requests)

Is there any easy way I can make it work on android?